Codex vaticanus assesment
Can anyone date the revelations manuscript present in the Codex Vaticanus , it seems that it's out of sync with the rest of the Codex and can anyone tell me whether there are scribal errors in the way the number 666 is written in Revelations 13:18.
Thank you

Do you mean Rev 13:18? Some manuscripts use χιϛ instead of χξϛ which converts to 616 instead of 666. The Wikipedia summary is pretty good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_of_the_beast but it does not list Codex Vaticanus as one those that uses 616 It also seems Codex Vaticanus doesn't actually include Revelation: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/15629/4150 or it was added later "The missing part of Hebrews and Revelation were supplemented by a 15th-century minuscule hand (folios 760–768), and are catalogued separately" per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codex_Vaticanus#Contents

Codex Vaticanus does not have the complete NT. The extant New Testament portion contains the Gospels, Acts, the general epistles, the Pauline epistles, and the Epistle to the Hebrews (up to Hebrews 9:14, καθα[ριει); it is lacking 1 and 2 Timothy, Titus, Philemon, and Revelation.   Therefore, what the text of the book of Revelation had in this codex is a moot question.

You may find you information here: Evidence from early manuscripts of Revelation 13:18?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@JamesShewey can we prove that the added manuscripts of revelation are from the 15 th century with accuracy? If so can you tell me how these are dated , thanks

@Tahir - Did you have a look at the linked Wikipedia citations? I'd start with "Aland, Kurt; Aland, Barbara (1995). The Text of the New Testament: An Introduction to the Critical Editions and to the Theory and Practice of Modern Textual Criticism. Erroll F. Rhodes (trans.). Grand Rapids, Michigan: William B. Eerdmans Publishing Company. p. 109. ISBN 978-0-8028-4098-1. but I am sure there are many others (including the other noted citations) You can view the original Codex online for yourself. Read the wiki for yourself.

I'm not going to do your homework for you... but I'll bet Pg. 109 of "The Text of the New Testament", pg 20 of " The Text and the Canon of the New Testament" and "Encyclopedia of Textual Criticism" all explain it pretty well and how we know revelation was a 15th century addition to the Codex and explains why the Vatican library chose not to include the addition.

@JamesSheweys Thank you

@JamesShewey i was going through the online version of the Codex u linked , I couldn't help but wonder why the initial pages along with the indexing is done in cursive , when that style of writing originated only around the 10th century , but we claim that the vaticanus is from the 4th century. Sorry if the question is stupid , I cannot read greek

@Tahir - I would presume it was added to help users more easily locate things in the manuscript. For example, I seriously doubt the stamps on page 1536 were original, but added by the librarian(s). Perhaps in the 15th century, for example.

@JamesShewey  its not just the indexing but also the first few textual pages ( could be more than a few but the first 7-8 looked about the same )

@JamesShewey could you find out why the first few textual pages (excluding indexing) are also in cursive?

@Tahir - in that case, I do not know. Perhaps that would make for a good new question.
